# How do I get the Date to work correctly on my app?

Tags: reactjs, api, date, time, constants

I am creating a weather app and would like to pull the day, date, month and year from the api to be displayed when I search for a city, when I put the code in below it just shows up as ${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}, is there a reason this is happening is it not properly getting the data from the api?

**App.js**

```
Import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { fetchWeather } from './api/fetchWeather';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

const dateBuilder = (d) => {
    let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"]
 let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

 let day = days[d.getDay()];
 let date = d.getDate();
 let month = months[d.getMonth()];
 let year = d.getFullYear();

 return '${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}'


}

const search = async (e) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter') {
        const data = await fetchWeather(query)
        

        setWeather(data);
        setQuery('');

         
    }
}
```

**fetchWeather.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const URL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
const API_KEY = '5a68c76873f7ccb04c1ef6f924b37e32';


export const fetchWeather = async (query) => {
const { data } = await axios.get(URL, {
    params: {

        q: query, 
        units: 'metric',
        APPID: API_KEY,
    }
});

return data
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks

```
return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`
```